# Importing function from other file which uses redux connect function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to import a function which uses props and actions from redux.

The onSearch.js file looks like this:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchItems as fetchItemsAction } from "a/b";

const onSearchFunction = ({
  ...
}) => {
    ...
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ ... }) => {
    ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    ...
});

export const onSearch = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(onSearchFunction);
```

And I am trying to import this onSearch function in other file like this:

```
import { onSearch } from "c/d";
```

but when I run this function in the other file, it gets an error: `Object(...) is not a function`

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Can you show the code calling onSearch as if it was a function?

Comment: Yes, it will be ```onChange={ () => onSearch() }```

Answer (score 0):

onSearch here is not a function:

```
 export const onSearch = connect(
```

You can pass a functional component to connect (although I don't know why, you can use the hooks) but what connect returns is not a function.